# Unable to use curl using kubernetes service's dns address

Tags: curl, kubernetes, kube-dns

I'm trying to perform `curl` to my pod from another pod in a Kubernetes cluster.

```sh
$ kubectl version --short
Client Version: v1.17.0
Server Version: v1.16.14
```

To do so, I tried the following commands:

```sh
$ kubectl run curl-performer --image=radial/busyboxplus:curl -i --tty --rm
If you don't see a command prompt, try pressing enter.

$  curl -XGET http://account-server.console.svc:9090
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'account-server.console.svc'
```

But `nslookup` works fine.

```sh
$ nslookup account-server.console.svc
Server:    10.245.0.10
Address 1: 10.245.0.10 kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local

Name:      account-server.console.svc
Address 1: 10.245.87.129 account-server.console.svc.cluster.local
```

What am I missing here?

**Update:**

Complete form of DNS address doesn't work either:

```sh
$ curl -XGET http://account-server.console.svc.cluster.local:9090
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'account-server.console.svc.cluster.local'
```

Comment: I think your dns name is referred incorrectly, it should follow this format `svc.namespace.svc.cluster.local`. Could you try with `curl -XGET http://account-server.console.svc.cluster.local:9090`?

Comment: @Jakub That doesn't work either. Updated my question.

Comment: What is your infrastructure? All you'r pods in kube-system are up and running? Could you check if you can curl it with  `service_ip:port` and `pod_ip:port`?